# realloc not working

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how realloc works. This is my program. It's giving some strange errors. Can anyone help me? I am just trying to do realloc for the array a. Any help appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[5]="abcd";
    char *p;
    p = realloc(a,10);
    strcpy(a,"abcdefghi");
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot realloc something that was allocated without using malloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass to `realloc` a pointer to memory allocated by `malloc` or one of its friends. In your code you are passing `a` which is a stack allocated variable.

Note that you cannot modify the size of stack allocated data so if your code does need to modify the size of a variable then that variable must be allocated on the heap.

Comment: I am just trying to extend the size of a from 5 to 10. Why should I use malloc?

Comment: Basically it boils down to that fact that you can't resize stack allocated values.

Comment: you mean I should use like: a = malloc(5); p = realloc(a, 10); Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `realloc` memory you didn't (originally) get via `malloc`, it's as simple as that.

Comment: All I want to see is extending the size of a from 5 to 10. Why are you saying I have to use malloc?

Comment: Yes, as others have stated. You can't realloc memory that wasn't originally allocated with malloc (or calloc). So if you want to realloc, you'll need to *alloc first.

Answer (score 2):

You can't realloc memory that wasn't alloc'ed via `malloc`, `calloc` (or similiar dynamic memory allocation function).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use malloc to allocate memory. After that you should use `p = realloc(a, 10 *sizeof(char))`

Comment: I tried that...It didn't work. Only after that I used 10 directly.

Comment: The first parameter of realloc: "Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc to be reallocated.
If this is NULL, a new block is allocated and a pointer to it is returned by the function."

Comment: `sizeof(char)` will always be `1`

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1 you have right. I wrote sizeof in the second parameter to help the questioner to know the proper parameter usage when using other types.